# How know if a Session is valid

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'd like to know the best way to know if a Session variable is still valid (session not expired, timeout). I'd like avoid the call a method on each action.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Filters. [This link shows you how](http://www.tyronedavisjr.com/2008/11/23/detecting-session-timeouts-using-a-aspnet-mvc-action-filter/)